# Where do I get an access token from to post to my facebook page using FBGraph gem in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am posting to a page on MY Facebook account from my web site using FBGraph gem but how do I get my access token?
I am certain that my code is correct to post to the page I need

```
  def send_fb_message(params = {})
    owner = FbGraph::User.me(FB_TOKEN)
    pages = owner.accounts
    page = pages.detect do |page|
      page.identifier == FB_PAGE_ID
    end
    page.feed!(
      :message => params[:message],
      :description => params[:description],
      :link => params[:link]        )
  end
```

As you can see FB_TOKEN is a constant, perhaps it should be a variable but whatever it needs to be I have no idea how to get the value for the access token. (All permissions have been accepted by my facebook account including manage_pages permission.)

I have a secret and an app id for my Facebook app and I'm using the graph api but there seems to be nowhere for me to make use of these.

The app login docs here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#applogin don't make it clear to me at all as to how to obtain the access token neither does the docs for the FBGraph gem unless I am missing something?

Is there a better way?

**UPDATE**

Thank's to the reply from @Lego below I have been able to make this post work using a token using the access token tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/. I can see the post if I am logged in as my user but I am unable to see the post if I am not logged in
How do I make this post public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround would be (but only if nothing else helps!) to ask yourself the offline_access permission and get yourself an access token via the [Access Token Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/) or the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer). Then you could hardcode the access token into your website (serverside). Since you gave your app the offline_access permission the token should not expire.

Comment: Thank you, I have done this which works after a fashion. I am unable to see the post that I have made unless I am logged in, How do I make the post public?

Comment: I'm going to ask this in a new question I think

Comment: Do you have the sandbox mode enabled in the advanced app settings?