# Using FBGraph with Rails 3 Problems posting to my own page on facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Following on from this post [Where do I get an access token from to post to my facebook page using FBGraph gem in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527125/where-do-i-get-an-access-token-from-to-post-to-my-facebook-page-using-fbgraph-ge) I am now able to make posts to my own facebook page but the posts are not visible to anyone other than me

I have all the privileges and I have an off line token. My facebook app settings for my account are set to public for my app.
Using the following code I can make posts, it's just that they are not isible to anyone.

How do I sort this out? Is it some approval process or app setting I have to make or is it down to my code? Totally stumped!

My code

```
  def send_fb_message(params = {})
    owner = FbGraph::User.me(FB_TOKEN)
    pages = owner.accounts
    page = pages.detect do |page|
      page.identifier == FB_PAGE_ID
    end
    page.feed!(
      :message => params[:message],
      :description => params[:description],
      :link => params[:link]
    )
  end
```

My FB_TOKEN constant is an offline access token supposedly for the user me, the FB_PAGE_ID constant is the id of the page I wish to post to.

I am using the Rails console to call the above method on my dev machine. Not sure if the location of the request makes a difference?

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the sandbox mode enabled in the advanced app settings?